# Python GIL: concurrent C++ embed

Tags: python, c++, multithreading, cpython, gil

Can python embedded into c++ allow you to run n python scripts concurrently?

I am currently dealing with the dread which is the GIL. My project requires concurrency of at least 2 threads and the easy typing in Python would really help with code simplicity.

Would embedding my Python code in a C++ script which deals with the threading circumvent the problems the GIL causes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can python embedded into c++ allow you to run n python scripts concurrently?

You don't need to do anything at all to be able to run multiple Python *scripts* concurrently. The GIL is local to the interpreter, so if you run multiple interpreter processes the GIL won't prevent them from executing concurrently.

If this is a typo and you mean *threads* then yes, you can call C or C++ code from Python to get around the GIL. See [Thread State and the Global Interpreter Lock](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html#thread-state-and-the-global-interpreter-lock) for details of the relevant APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Only if you spawn separate interpreters.
GIL is one-per-interpreter policy to protect interpreter internals. One interpreter will run one line at a time.

The only other way is to program at least one of your threads in pure C++ and offer a communication queue API to your python script or any way to communicate asynchronously really.

Comment: I don't believe the second paragraph to be correct. A C++ extension could release the GIL, thereby enabling concurrency with other similar threads and with the Python interpreter thread.